# preg_match_all: changing the string $match

Tags: php, preg-match-all

So far: I'm doing a preg_match_all search and my output is: Donald, Daisy, Huey, Dewey and Louie

Code is like this:

```
$duckburg = array();
preg_match_all($pattern,$subject,$match);
$duckburg['residents'] = $match[1];
print_r($duckburg['residents']);
```

Output:

```
Array ( [residents] => Array ( [0] => Donald [1] => Daisy [2] => Huey [3] => Dewey [4] => Louie )
```

My question: I would like to add to every string " Duck"

Using this help-string: `$lastname = " Duck"`

The output should be:

```
Array ( [residents] => Array ( [0] => Donald Duck [1] => Daisy Duck [2] => Huey Duck [3] => Dewey Duck [4] => Louie Duck )
```

I tried (but it's not working):

```
preg_match_all($pattern,$subject,$match);
$matchy = $match.$lastname;
$duckburg['residents'] = $matchy[1];
print_r($duckburg['residents']);
```

Is it possible to change the matching string before it goes into the array? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Use `$duckburg['residents'] = $matchy;` istead of `$duckburg['residents'] = $matchy[1];
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) is the tool for such manipulation:

```
$match = Array ( 'residents' => Array ('Donald','Daisy','Huey','Dewey','Louie'));
$duckburg['residents'] = array_map(function($n) { return "$n Duck"; }, $match['residents']);
var_dump($duckburg);
```

**Output:**

```
array(1) {
  ["residents"]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    string(11) "Donald Duck"
    [1]=>
    string(10) "Daisy Duck"
    [2]=>
    string(9) "Huey Duck"
    [3]=>
    string(10) "Dewey Duck"
    [4]=>
    string(10) "Louie Duck"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the array is one possible option:

```
$lastname = " Duck";
preg_match_all($pattern,$subject,$matches);
foreach($matches as $key => $val){
    $duckburg['residents'][$key] = $val . $lastname;
}
print_r($duckburg['residents']);
```